# Inheritance type casting compilation error

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I am trying to understand how inhertitance and ArrayList work, so I have this following code
It has a class which is the database where data will be saved

```
public class Database {
    ArrayList<Student> students;
    ArrayList<Course> courses;

    public boolean doesIDExist(ArrayList<RegistrationSystem> array, int id){
       boolean exist = false;
       for (RegistrationSystem array1 : array) {
           if (array1.getId() == id) {
              exist = true;
              break;
           }
       }
       return exist;
    }

    public boolean addStudent(int id, String name, String surname){
       if( doesIDExist(students, id)){
           return false;
       }

       students.add(new Student(id, name, surname));
       return true;
    }

}
```

Both Student and Course are subclasses of Registration System

```
public class RegistrationSystem  {
   protected int id;

   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
}
```

But I get an error in this line:

```
       if( doesIDExist(students, id))
```

`incompatible types: ArrayList< Student > cannot be converted to ArrayList< RegistrationSystem >`

I cannot quite understand why I get this error!

Comment: You probably want to make that `RegistrationSystem` superclass an interface instead... Saying Student "is a" RegistrationSystem or Course "is a" RegistrationSystem makes no sense, so having an inheritance relationship between them probably makes no sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `Student` is a subtype of `RegistrationSystem`, it is *not* the case that `ArrayList<Student>` is a subtype of `ArrayList<RegistrationSystem>`.

The reason for this, is that this could result in non-type-safe code. Consider the following code:

```
void method1(ArrayList<RegistrationSystem> listOfRegistrationSystems) {
    listOfRegistrationSystems.add(new Course()); 
}
void method2() {
    ArrayList<Student> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<>();
    method1(listOfStudents);
    Student student = listOfStudents.get(0);
    // Ooops! The first element of listOfStudents is not a Student!
}
```

To solve this, Java provides *bounded* type variables and bounded wildcards. You can use the `ArrayList<? extends RegistrationSystem>`, which means: an `ArrayList` of instances of some unknown subclass of `RegistrationSystem`. In your case, `ArrayList<? extends RegistrationSystem>` can be one of `ArrayList<RegistrationSystem>`, `ArrayList<Student>` or `ArrayList<Course>`. So you have to change your method to

```
public boolean doesIDExist(ArrayList<? extends RegistrationSystem> array, int id){
    boolean exist = false;
    for (RegistrationSystem array1 : array) {
        if (array1.getId() == id) {
            exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return exist;
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. To add to this, its worth noting that: a) the generic type itself _can_ be substituted in calling statements for one of its subtypes (e.g. a method that takes `List<? extends Number>` could accept `ArrayList<Integer>`) and b) when using the wildcard syntax as discussed you will only be able to get instances of the upper bounded type (e.g. `RegistrationSystem` out of the collection and most importantly you cannot put anything _into_ the collection - see [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 5):

Your method expected a List of `RegistrationSystem` not a List of `Student`.

You have to change to:

```
public boolean doesIDExist(ArrayList<? extends RegistrationSystem> array, int id){
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth to explain the upper bounded wildcards a bit more in detail and not only present the solution here. see [Oracle tutorial - upper bounded wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Comment: to expand on @Jens answer, neither `ArrayList<Student>` or `ArrayList<Course>` are subtypes of `ArrayList<RegistrationSystem>`; you must use the wildcard syntax `? extends RegistrationSystem` in this scenario to make your methods flexible enough to accept a collection of any subtype of `RegistrationSystem`

Answer (score 1):

In here `if( doesIDExist(students, id)`, You are passing `Student` objects instead of `RegistrationSystem` objects. As a better option you have to implement a new method to identify the existing student id's

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to do here is something like this:

`ArrayList<RegistrationSystem> array =  students;`

Java does not allow this

Change your method signature do this instead `doesIDExist(ArrayList<? extends RegistrationSystem>,int id)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an ArrayList of Student objects, when the method accepts RegistrationSystem only.